# Problemas con Collections.sort y reverse en Java

Tags: java, lista, ordenamiento

Tengo una lista de listas de números (String) los cuales el usuario define si los quiere ordenar de mayor a menor o menor a mayor:

```
for(int i =0; i < original.size(); i++){
    if(TD == 1){ //ASCEDENTE
        Collections.sort(original.get(i));
    }else{ //Descendente
        Collections.reverse(original.get(i));
    }
}
```

Esté método lo hago dos veces, ambas después de que agrego nuevos elementos a la lista.
El problema es que la primera que lo ejecuto lo acomoda como el usuario decide, pero la segunda vez lo acomoda mal, si es de manera descendente me lo hace ascendente, si es ascendente no lo acomoda correctamente.

¿Alguien sabe porque ocurre esto y como corregirlo?

La lista es de String

Comment: Creo que en el método sort los deberías de cambiar a Integer para que el ordenamiento no tenga problemas

Comment: Lo hice pero resulta lo mismo

Comment: Si ya lo pasaste a una lista numérica te recomendaría cambiar simplemente a: `original.sort((a, b) -> a - b);` para ascendente y `original.sort((a, b) -> b - a);` para descendente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te hace falta recorrer la lista para ordenarla o hacer un reverse.

Basta con que, al cumplir la condición, ordenes la lista o si no, hacerle un reverse, previamente ordenándola.

**Ejemplo**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean check = true;

    lista.add("12");
    lista.add("1");
    lista.add("26");
    lista.add("56");
    lista.add("34");

    if (check) {
        Collections.sort(lista);
    } else {
        Collections.sort(lista);
        Collections.reverse(lista);
    }

    System.out.println(lista);
}
```

Output cuando la condición se cumple:

```
[1, 12, 26, 34, 56]
```

Output cuando la condición no se cumple:

```
[56, 34, 26, 12, 1]
```

Comment: Este método va a generar un problema pues los ordena "alfabéticamante".
Intenta con la siguiente lista `ArrayList <String> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("5", "10", "23", "-8", "89", "19", "100"));`

Comment: Como resultado del anterior comentario, el output sería
`[-8, 10, 100, 19, 23, 5, 89]` | `[89, 5, 23, 19, 100, 10, -8]` pues compara el "100" con el "19" e internamente se hace la comparación de "0" y "9" dando como resultado que "100" es menor a "19"

Comment: Aplicar sort y después reverse fue lo que me funcionó, creo que malentendí lo que hacia reverse

Comment: @BarHector, ten cuidado pues como expuse en los comentarios anteriores no compara el valor numérico, compara el valor alfabético

Comment: De hecho pase la lista a enteros para hacer el acomodo

Comment: Ok, entonces no hay problema :D

Answer (score 1):

Como recomendación te recomendaría hacer uso de [Comparators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) para tener un mejor control sobre cómo se hace el sort de los Elementos.

En este caso lo manejé con el [Integer.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)), si fuera con decimales no hay problema en usar [Double.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-)

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <String> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("5", "10", "23", "-8", "89", "19"));
        numbers.sort(new AscendingIntegerSort());
        System.out.println(numbers);
        numbers.sort(new DescendingIntegerSort());
        System.out.println(numbers);

    }

    protected static class AscendingIntegerSort implements Comparator<String> {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
        }
    }

    protected static class DescendingIntegerSort implements Comparator<String> {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return - Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[-8, 5, 10, 19, 23, 89]
[89, 23, 19, 10, 5, -8]
```

Si quieres evitar hacer uso de la implementación del comparador puedes simplemente usar el método [List.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-)

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <String> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("5", "10", "23", "-8", "89", "19"));
        // También se puede hacer uso del Integer.valueOf()
        // De hecho yo lo recomendaría en vez del Integer.parseInt()
        numbers.sort((a, b) -> Integer.parseInt(a) - Integer.parseInt(b));
        System.out.println(numbers);
        numbers.sort((a, b) -> Integer.parseInt(b) - Integer.parseInt(a));
        System.out.println(numbers);

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[-8, 5, 10, 19, 23, 89]
[89, 23, 19, 10, 5, -8]
```

**Anotaciones**
Como verás en este caso se hace la resta entera de a y b para definir el sentido del ordenamiento.

Internamente ***sort*** hace el ordenamiento de acuerdo a si el argumento que se le pasa es positivo, negativo o cero

Comment: Pues esto ya es extra, pero si quieres conocer un poco más acerca de Comparator, en [esta pregunta auto respondida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463512/java-aplicar-ordenamientos-consecutivos-a-clases-que-heredan-del-mismo-padre/463513#463513) tengo una explicación que te podría servir