# Utilizar el metodo sort en Java

Tags: java, array, clase, ordenamiento

He creado una clase y su método main. En mi clase llamada "Arreglos" he declarado una variable llamada numeros con sus setters, getters y constructores.
En el método main declaro un arreglo con el tipo de la clase Arreglos(la que yo he creado), luego con un for lo voy rellenando a ese arreglo que he creado en el main con números aleatorios reales.

Aca surge mi problema: No entiendo por que me lanza un error cuando quiero ordenar mi arreglo con el método sort si es correcto la llamada y el parametro que le estoy pasando a ese método.
Necesitaria que me ordene los numeros aleatorios de menor a mayor pero me lanza un error y no comprendo el por que.

```
public class EjercicioArreglos {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
      
        
        Arreglos[] arregloA = new Arreglos[20];
     
        System.out.println("ARREGLO A");
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
            arregloA[i] = new Arreglos(Math.random()*(10+1));
        }
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
      
            System.out.println(arregloA[i].getNumeros());
        }
      
        Arrays.sort(arregloA);
        
      
        
    }
    
}

public class Arreglos {
   
   private double numeros;
    
   public Arreglos(){
       
   }
   
   public Arreglos(double numeros){
       this.numeros = numeros;
   }
   
   public void setNumeros(double numeros){
       this.numeros = numeros;
   }
   
   public double getNumeros(){
       return numeros;
   }
   
   
   
}
```

Comment: Es diferente hacer sort de una clase a hacer sort de un número, eso es lo que te está sucediendo. Creo que había una pregunta similar, deja la busco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es muy distinto hacer comparaciones de datos primitivos a hacer comparaciones de Clases, como puedes ver, estás creando una clase que almacena un double. Realmente no sé para qué pero eso está pasando. Entonces, Java no puede saber si la instancia de la clase en la posición 1 es más grande que la de la posición 7 o menor que la posición 10.

Para ello necesita un [comparador](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) que le diga con base en qué debe comparar las clases:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        OwnArrays[] array1 = new OwnArrays[20];

        System.out.println("ARREGLO A");

        for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
            array1[i] = new OwnArrays(Math.random() * ( 10 + 1));
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
        Arrays.sort(array1, new DoubleComparator());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));

    }

    private static class DoubleComparator implements Comparator<OwnArrays> {
        @Override
        public int compare(OwnArrays o1, OwnArrays o2) {
            return Double.compare(o1.getNumbers(), o2.getNumbers());
        }
    }

    private static class OwnArrays {

        private double numbers;

        public OwnArrays(double numbers){
            this.numbers = numbers;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(numbers);
        }

        public double getNumbers(){
            return numbers;
        }

    }
}
```

Si es clase sólo almacena el valor como se muestra en la figura, bien puedes usar el dato primitivo [double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) o la clase [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html) y las cosas se simplificarían mucho:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Double[] array1 = new Double[20];

        System.out.println("ARREGLO A");
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
            array1[i] = (Math.random() * ( 10 + 1));


        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
        Arrays.sort(array1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));

    }
}
```

Comment: Si quieres aplicar ordenamientos consecutivos en el objeto con base en distintas propiedades de una o más clases tal vez te interese leer [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463512/java-aplicar-ordenamientos-consecutivos-a-clases-que-heredan-del-mismo-padre/463513#463513)

Comment: Los *Comparator* no son siempre necesarios. Si una clase implementa *Comparable*, que establece un orden natural, *sort()* puede usar el método *compareTo* para ordenar y no necesita un *Comparator* (aunque le puedes pasar uno si quieres ordenar siguiendo otro criterio).

Answer (score 3):

lo que pasa es es que estas intentando acomodar un objeto creado sin definir como es que se debe hacer, para que eso funcionara tal y como lo lo tienes tu arreglo debaría de ser un tipo de dato primitivo por ejemplo int

```
 int[] arr = {13, 7, 6, 45, 21, 9, 2, 100};
    Arrays.sort(arr);
```

pero en tu caso eso no funcionará, puede hacerlo haciendo un comparador en donde indique sobre que atributo de su objeto se hará el orden :

```
class ComparadorNumero implements Comparator<Arreglos> {
public int compare(Arreglos a, Arreglos b)
{
    return a.numeros - b.numeros;
}
}
```

y posteriormente lo mandas como parametro en tu sort:

```
Arrays.sort(arregloA, new ComparadorNumero ());
```

Comment: También funciona con algunas clases como Double, Short, Integer, etc. No sólo para datos primitivos, aunque va por ahí

Comment: Los *Comparator* no son siempre necesarios. Si una clase implementa *Comparable*, que establece un orden natural, *sort()* puede usar el método *compareTo* para ordenar y no necesita un *Comparator* (aunque le puedes pasar uno si quieres ordenar siguiendo otro criterio). @EduardoJiménez, para Double, Short y demás funciona porque implementan *Comparable*

Answer (score 2):

El error es porque el método `Arrays.sort(Object [] array)` requiere saber cómo comparar los objetos para poder ordenarlos. La forma más sencilla de hacerlo es que los objetos sean comparables: deben implementar la interfaz `Comparable`:

```
public class Arreglos implements Comparable<Arreglos> {
   
    private double numeros;
       
    ... //getters, setters y constructores
   
    public int compareTo(Arreglos otroArreglo) {
        if (otroArreglo == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return Double.compare(this.numeros, otroArreglo.numeros);
    }
   
}
```