# Como ordenar un arreglo bidimensional por campos donde cada campo es una columna?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, array-bidimensional

me gustaria saber como ordenar un arreglo bidimensional por campos segun el campo que el usuario elija.

```
private static final int filas = 4;
private static final int columnas = 5;
String libro[][] = new String[Datos.filas][Datos.columnas];
```

Las columnas seria igual a los campos: Codigo, Nombre, Autor, Materia, N° Paginas

Ejemplo de como se veria el arreglo original:

| Codigo | Nombre | Autor | Materia | N° Paginas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Como programar en Java | Paul Deitel | Programacion | 1200 |
| 2 | Libro 2 | Autor 2 | Materia 2 | 500 |
| 7 | Libro 3 | Autor 3 | Materia 3 | 600 |
| 5 | Libro 4 | Autor 4 | Materia 4 | 700 |

Ejemplo de lo que necesito, si el usuario escoje ordenar por numero de paginas:

| Codigo | Nombre | Autor | Materia | N° Paginas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Libro 2 | Autor 2 | Materia 2 | 500 |
| 7 | Libro 3 | Autor 3 | Materia 3 | 600 |
| 5 | Libro 4 | Autor 4 | Materia 4 | 700 |
| 4 | Como programar en Java | Paul Deitel | Programacion | 1200 |

Mi idea era hacerlo creando un metodo que reciba un int de 1 a 5 que hace alusion a la categoria y de esa forma ordenar el arreglo, pero no he sido capaz.

```
public void ordenarArreglo(int ordenarPorCampo){
     if(ordenarPorCampo == 1){
         //Ordenar por campo codigo
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer uso de [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html),
Los comparadores se pueden pasar a un método de clasificación como `Collections.sort Arrays.sort` pero al ser tu array bidimensional de tipo `String` deberás realizar un cast en los datos numéricos..debes tener en cuenta que los indices en un array parten de 0 pero el dato ordenarPorCampo  si es que hace referencia a la primera columna deber ser pasado como 1

```java
public static void ordenarArreglo(int ordenarPorCampo,String[][]libro){
    switch(ordenarPorCampo-1){
        case 1,2,3 -> Arrays.sort(libro, Comparator.comparing(a -> a[ordenarPorCampo-1].toLowerCase()));
        case 0,4 ->   Arrays.sort(libro, Comparator.comparing(b -> Integer.parseInt(b[ordenarPorCampo-1])));
        default-> System.out.println("Indice Incorrecto");
    }

    for (int i=0; i<libro.length; i++) {

        for (int j=0; j<libro[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(libro[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta (+1). Solo comentarle al OP que si usa Java < 14 o tiene configurado en su ide un nivel del lenguaje < 14, las expresiones switch no funcionarán.

Comment: Gran respuesta, sólo tengo duda, ¿El comparing de los String es `case sensitive`? porque también sería bueno adecuado checar ese caso

Comment: Si lo es, buen punto

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo te recomendaría es usar una estructura diferente para tu trabajo. Aprovechemos que es un lenguaje **Orientado a Objetos** entonces creemos una clase ***Book***

```java
public class Book {

    private final String name;
    private final String author;
    private final String subject;
    private final int pages;

    public Book(String name, String author, String subject, int pages) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Name: %s\tAuthor: %s\tSubject: %s\tPages: %d\n***********************************\n",
                name,
                author,
                subject,
                pages
        );
    }
}
```

Ahí ya compactamos las propiedades y tenemos una mejor organización; pero hace falta el ordenamiento, para ello usaremos [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) y recomendaría crear una clase anidada para cada comparador. Es decir, usaremos clases dentro de la clase Book.

Como nota final para comparar String, usaremos `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(s1, s2)`

```java
public class Book {
    /*
        El resto de la clase (propiedades, constructor, etc.)
        ...
    */

    public static class OrderBookByName implements Comparator<Book> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
            return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(o1.name, o2.name);
        }
    }

    public static class OrderBookByAuthor implements Comparator<Book> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
            return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(o1.author, o2.author);
        }
    }

    public static class OrderBookBySubject implements Comparator<Book> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
            return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(o1.subject, o2.subject);
        }
    }

    public static class OrderBookByPages implements Comparator<Book> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.pages, o2.pages);
        }
    }
```

Finalmente la implementación termina siendo tan sencilla como

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>(3);
        books.add(new Book("Cómo programar en Java", "Paul Deitel", "Backend", 1200));
        books.add(new Book("Aprendiendo C", "Cobalt Rick", "Backend", 1800));
        books.add(new Book("Cómo programar en Cobol", "Blanca de Jesús", "Base de datos", 600));
        books.add(new Book("Entendiendo Linux", "Hugo Rafael", "Servidores", 200));
        books.add(new Book("Introducción a HTML, CSS y JS", "Karla Ortega", "Front end", 800));

        // Ejemplo de uso
        books.sort(new Book.OrderBookByName());
        books.forEach(System.out::print);

    }

}
```

## Resultados

**Por nombre**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Por páginas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Beneficios

1. El mantenimiento del código es más sencillo
2. Te permite usar arreglos dinámicos, si necesitas agregar o quitar libros se puede hacer con facilidad
3. No tendrás que preocuparte de si el índice 1 es el nombre o es el autor, pues ya están definidas en una clase y te permite acceder a los estados de tu objeto (variables)
4. Con el punto anterior se resaltan los beneficios de: modularidad, reutilización de código, ocultamiento de información y capacidad de conexión y facilidad de depuración (véase el [tutorial de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html))

## Normalización

Si lo ves necesario, dentro de las clases que implementan Comparator puedes normalizar tu texto. Para que las letras acentuadas no te causen problemas.

Del ejemplo anterior agregaremos un nuevo libro

```java
books.add(new Book("Árboles binarios", "Paul Deitel", "Estructuras de datos", 1200));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ejecutamos el programa veremos que la Á al tener acento no es ordenada correctamente, pues recordemos que el ordenamiento de los String, sigue los estándares de ASCII. Pero lo podemos solucionar con un simple método

```
public class Book {

    /* El resto de la clase */

    private String normalizeString(String str) {
        return Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                .replaceAll("[\\u0300-\\u036f]", "");
    }

    public static class OrderBookByName implements Comparator<Book> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
            return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(o1.normalizeString(o1.name), o2.normalizeString(o2.name));
        }
    }
}
```

Y listo. **Corregido**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Aún mejor

Para evitar la normalización, podemos hacer uso de [Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html) como nos explica [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html). Entonces como variable de clase declaramos un `collator` con el Locale que queramos usar. En este caso se usa el default de la máquina.

```java
private static Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
```

Y los comparadores quedan como

```java
public static class OrderBookByName implements Comparator<Book> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
        return collator.compare(o1.name, o2.name);
    }
}
```

Este método es mejor, pues tiene consideraciones propias de la región que no se toman en cuenta al normalizar el texto

Comment: Si quieres, de hecho se pueden ordenar consecutivamente; es decir, si quieres ordenarlos por Materia, Autor y Nombre en esa prioridad, es posible. Si lo ves necesario o te es útil, te invito a leer esta otra [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463512/java-aplicar-ordenamientos-consecutivos-a-clases-que-heredan-del-mismo-padre), pero en este caso es más sencillo pues es a la misma clase, no a clases hijas de un padre común